# Append index to href

Tags: jquery, each

I have an unordered list of links that I need to append the index as a number to.

So `href="#"` reads `href="#1"`, `href="#2"` etc.

I understand I probably need to use `.each()` but my syntax-fu isn't up to scratch yet.

Part of me knows this is ridiculously simple but I'm having a monday atm.

Comment: Unordered list as in `<ul>`?  Or just arbitrarily in the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's Sunday but..

```
$("#myList li").each(function(index) {
    $(this).find("a").attr("href", "#" + (index + 1));
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/yahavbr/mKdWw/).

Comment: @Fortinbrass: It's not so much a learning tool, as a testbed.  But it is very useful indeed.

Comment: ill take whatever i can get to get up to speed so for me its a learning tool and a testbed

Comment: @Fort join the club.. learned about it in my first day here as well. Please accept Felix answer, it's quite the same like my own just little better.

Comment: @Fort to have someone see when you post comment use `@`, e.g. `@Orb` will be enough for Orbling to see your above comment. :)

Comment: @Fort not more than what I (and probably everyone else ;)) was in the beginning. Took me weeks to learn about the `@` stuff, when directed to the person who wrote the question or answer it's not needed, he gets notification anyway - it's required only when you want the attention of somebody else who commented. :)

Comment: @Fortinbrass: And there are tools that make it easier: http://stackapps.com/questions/2051/reply-links-on-comments

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean the index of the element in the set of selected elements? If so you can use [**`.attr()`**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and pass a function to it:

```
$('a').attr('href', function(i, value) {
    return value + (i+1);
});
```

Of course you have to select only those links you want, e.g. by giving your list an ID:

```
$('#theList a')
```

---

**Update:**

**There seems to be a bug in jQuery 1.3.2 (and before).** [It seems the old value is not passed to the callback](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/mKdWw/1/). So you would have to read the value explicitly:

```
return this.href + (i+1);
```

Of course if the old value is always `#` then you can just concatenate it with the index:

```
return '#' + (i+1);
```

But in this case, you could use `each()` in this case, as [@Shadow Wizard shows in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5289607/append-index-to-href/5289638#5289638). The advantage of passing a function to `attr` is only that you avoid two access to the attribute (one to read and one to write), which does not seems to work in jQuery 1.3.2 anyway.

Comment: I think he means index in the list, not global links collection.

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: Well, he can narrow down the selection by using an appropriate selector.

Comment: should mention that i'm restricted to jquery 1.3.2 because of another script's compatibility

Comment: @Fortinbrass: According to the documentation, the possibility to pass a function was introduced in jQuery 1.1.

Comment: @Felix yep, your answer look better as well (iterating the `a` directly), kudos and plus my meager 1. :)

Comment: and value would be href according to this ?

Comment: @Fortinbrass: Yes, `value` would be the current value of the `href` attribute. Unfortunately it seems not to work in jQuery 1.3.2 for whatever reason. See my updated answer.

Comment: the example @shadow wizard used on jsfiddle gives the correct outcome - im just now trying to implement it within these restrctions

Comment: @Fortinbrass: Ah I missed that you want to start the numbering at `1`. Fixed.

Comment: @Felix how you link to specific Answer? Don't want to ask on `Meta` and look n00bish.. :-)

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: :D Below the text of each answer are three links : `link`, `edit` and `flag`. I just copied the `link` link...

Comment: @Felix wow, feeling really lucky I didn't ask this on Meta.. **thanks**! :P

Comment: @Shadow Wizard: hehe you're welcome :) No worries, I didn't know that this link exists for a long time too ;)

Comment: @all - thanks this worked in the end - now i just need to beat this coda slider's cross-linking into shape

Comment: @Fortinbrass: You're welcome :) Don't forget to accept one of the answers that helped you the most by clicking on the tick outline next to it. You can always upvote the other answers that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

Easier to use the [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function.

```
$('ul a').attr("href", function(index, cHRef) {
    return cHRef + index;
});
```

If you are restricted to older jQuery implementations older than v1.1, then you will need to use [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$('ul a').each(function(index, cAnchor) {
    cAnchor.attr('href', cAnchor.attr('href') + index);
});
```